# Suppose we have a C++ string called success. What is the difference between &success and success&?

Tags: c++

Question: Suppose we have a C++ string called `success`. What is the difference between `&success` and `success&`?

This question is from my midterm review, I understand that `&success` is getting the address of the object. But I am not sure what `success&` is?

Comment: It depends on the context, can you provide the examples in code?

Comment: This is the question I got without any other additional information, but according to the answers here, I don't think he will want me to put syntax error. I think my teacher meant to use string& not success&. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `success` is a variable and not the name of a type then it's invalid syntax by itself.

Answer (score 2):

If `success` is a variable then the expression `success&` is invalid and the compiler would complain, on the other hand if it is type `success&` would mean a reference to the type.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaken with the following expression.
The data type below means a reference to a string object whose contents will not be changed.

```
const string&
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` has two meanings.
I'm assuming that `success` is a variable and not a struct or class name as so:
`std::string success = "myString"`

**1. To refer to the address of the variable**

If you refer to success  as `&success` anywhere except in declaration or function parameter(formal argument) list, it is a reference to the address of that variable.
In your case, it `&success` would return the actual raw memory address where "myString" is stored in.

**2. Reference Variable**

If you see the `&` where the variable is declared or in a function's parameter (formal argument) list as

`std::string& success;`

Or

```
void swap(std::string& success, std::string& failure);
```

it is the syntax for a reference variable which are basically syntax sugar for pointers. Such variables refer to the same values as other variables do and can be assigned only once through the assignment operator or member initializer lists.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the "syntactical sugar"-part. references are a not totally different to pointers but for sure not only "syntactical sugar".